# Writing to HDFS With Put Command, getting "Exculding datanode"

Tags: java, hadoop

### When I use "hadoop fs -put file1.txt /home",got these errors:

```
2014-11-25 12:42:27 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation] fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-11-25 12:45:34 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1341)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1167)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1122)

at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:522)
2014-11-25 12:46:09 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] Abandoning BP-303063678-192.168.73.110-1416777303478:blk_1073741831_1007
2014-11-25 12:46:42 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] Excluding datanode 192.168.73.100:50010
2014-11-25 12:51:07 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1341)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1167)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:522)
2014-11-25 12:51:15 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] Abandoning BP-303063678-192.168.73.110-1416777303478:blk_1073741832_1008
2014-11-25 12:51:25 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] Excluding datanode 192.168.73.107:50010
2014-11-25 12:51:25 WARN [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /home/file1.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and 2 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1433)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2688)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:569)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:440)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1406)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1359)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1264)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1112)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:522)
2014-11-25 12:51:25 ERROR [org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient] Failed to close file /home/file1.txt
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /home/file1.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and 2 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1433)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2688)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:569)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:440)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1406)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1359)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1264)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1112)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:522)
```

---

**And i have tried as the network descripe:
     1. stop-all.sh
     2. hadoop namenode -format
     3. drop the dfs/name ,dfs/data
     4. start-all.sh
I also have set all the dir permissions  with chmod 777 .**
    But these don't work ,how i can do ?

Comment: are you use hadoop in standalone or pseudomode??

Comment: no ,it's distributed .one master,two slaves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some setting in multi node cluster like--

```
SSH access
setting in conf/masters (master only)
setting in conf/slaves (master only)
setting in conf/*-site.xml (all machines)
```

so follow this link steps by step all the settings are given, 
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

let me know if not solved;